# Authorization/Authentication in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I need to create a couple of simple methods using asp.net web api. I am very new to this so even the simplest thing is proving difficult for me. I want to decorate my api controller with [authorize] and [authenticate] for the obvious reasons.

My question is centred on how I call these methods from my ajax calls (which is how I'm intending to call them). I'm reading that I need to pass the user id and password with each of my calls but how do I do this using ajax? Or do I even need to do this manually or asp.net somehow does it for me (if that even makes any sense)? Because when I'm doing action calls that need to be authenticated/authorized using forms in mvc, I certainly don't do it expressly and I imagine somehow somewhere in the code it just gets done.

As is clear, I'm very lost. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you setting up authentication and authorization in your Setup/Program file?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to pass username and password. It depends on your authentication method. Which authentication provider will you be using? AAD, Google, FB, Custom? As an example if you use AAD authentication, you do not need to pass anything, it all just works magically with cookies. Is this an enterprise application (i.e. being built for a specific company), or will it be a public one? If it's a public one you should use one of many third party auth providers such as google or facebook

Comment: As per the first comment your first step is to pick an auth provider and build a basic authenticated MVC app

Comment: I'm using asp.net's Identity if that's what you guys are asking about. I'm using the registration by user id and password on the site and am not using any 3rd party authentication system. To make things a bit more clear (at least in my head), I am not advanced enough to use anything custom. All MVC/web api's baked-in system.

Comment: I'm confused. So the built-in mvc identity won't work and I'd have to pick a 3rd party such as google/Facebook? If so please explain why and if I'm misunderstanding, then sorry but I need clarification.

Comment: Built in MVC idenity probably will work I've never tried it. It's certainly an authorization provider. Does it support the `[Authorize]` decorator? I assume it does. I suggest you find and build some sample code that uses the `[Authorize]` decorater. As I understand it whether you call a controller from a view, or whether you call it from Javascript/AJAX, it will require authorisation. I suggest you edit the question and add the info about using built in mvc identity for authorization

Comment: Rereading your question: Just add the decorators and test them. You should be able to call the methods from JS without passing any auth info because the built in auth magic (processing pipeline) already knows what you logged in as.

Comment: First step is build this and confirm it works. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-identity-in-simple-ways-using-asp-net-mvc-5 Next step is add some Ajax to call the "secured" method which is `Test/Identity` and confirm that it works fine if you previously logged in, and doesn't work if you didn't